# Calculating standard error of maximum likelihood estimate

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

Suppose that $X$ is a discrete random variable with
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 &2&3 \\
2θ/3& θ/3 & 2(1-θ)/3 &(1-θ)/3
\end{pmatrix}

where $0\le θ\le 1$ is a parameter.

10 independent observations were taken: $( 3,0,2,1,3,2,1,0,2,2)$

1)What is the maximum likehood estimate of $θ$?

2) What is the approximate standard error of the maximumlikehood estimate.

(Question similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114419/calculating-the-standard-error-of-a-maximum-likelihood-estimator).)

1):
$$L(\theta) = P(X=0| \theta)^2 P(X=1| \theta)^2 P(X=2| \theta)^4 P(X=3| \theta)^2= \bigg( \frac{2}{3} \theta \bigg)^2  \bigg( \frac{1}{3} \theta \bigg)^2  \bigg( \frac{2}{3} (1- \theta) \bigg)^4  \bigg( \frac{1}{3} (1-\theta) \bigg)^2\\$$

\begin{align*} 
l(\theta) &=2 ln( \frac{2}{3} \theta) + 2 ln( \frac{1}{3} \theta)+ 4 ln( \frac{2}{3} (1- \theta) )+ 2 ln ( \frac{1}{3} (1-\theta) )\\
\end{align*}

$$l'(\theta)= \frac{2}{\theta}+ \frac{2}{\theta}- \frac{4}{1-\theta}- \frac{2}{1-\theta} =  \frac{4}{\theta}- \frac{6}{1-\theta}$$

We say first derivate is zero and we get the estimate:
\begin{align*} 
\hat{\theta}  &= \frac{4}{10} = \frac{2}{5}
\end{align*}

So far, everything is correct.

2): I am stuck on this part as I get the wrong result, and I don't know why. Here is my path to solution:

$$l''(\theta)= \frac{-4}{\theta^2}- \frac{6}{(1-\theta)^2}.$$

\begin{align*}
E(l''(\theta)) &= \frac{-4}{\theta^2}- \frac{6}{(1-\theta)^2}
\end{align*}

We calculate standard  error (we insert $\hat{\theta}=0.4$):
$$se_{\hat{\theta}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-E(l''(\hat{\theta}))}} = \sqrt{\frac{\hat{\theta}^2(1-\hat{\theta})^2}{4 - 8\hat{\theta}+10\hat{\theta}^2}} = 0.024.$$

Where  did  I do the mistake?

Comment: I am pretty sure you forgot the square root! $\sqrt{0.024} \approx 0.155$.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I've been doing some more research and in some literature I found, I should also divide the result with $\sqrt{10}$. I dont think this is correct, because the result is then way too small.